# how to read a txt file containing matrix form of data into 2d array of same dimensions as in the file using java

Tags: java

here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class csvimport5 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        double [][] data = new double [87][2];  
        File file = new File("buydata.txt");
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;


        //read each line of text file
        while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < data.length)
        {   
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            //get next token and store it in the array
            data[row][col] = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            col++;
        }
        col = 0;
        row++;
        }

        System.out.println(" "+data[87][2]);  

      }

    }
```

it shows error:-numberformatException :empty string

pls help me

Answer (score 2):

At some point in your file, the st.nextToken() is returning an empty string. Because you're trying to parse that into a Double, you're getting an error (there are no numbers in an empty string to get a double from).

The most common reason for this is bad input data. Are you able to provide a subset of your buydata.txt file, which causes the bug to occur?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Erica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828491/how-to-read-a-txt-file-containing-matrix-form-of-data-into-2d-array-of-same-dimen/5828586#5828586), the cause of the error is some badly formatted string in your input file, which cause `parseDouble()` to throw a `NumberFormatException`. You should sorround it into a `try ... catch`. You could something like this:

```
// set val to a constant value that you know is not acceptable
dobule val = UNACCEPTABLE_VALUE;
String token = st.nextToken();

try {
  val = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  System.err.println("bad value: " + token + " at line: " + line);
}

data[row][col] = val;

col++
```