# Read text file to arrayList and sort

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist, split, java.util.scanner

This is a snippet of my txt file "Q.txt".

```
12.54778255173505 :      ^FinishedLine
15.416218875438748 :  
 ^FinishedLine
16.245508427720914 :  ^FinishedLine
9.595696051997852 :   &^FinishedLine
11.971100145959943 : ! '^FinishedLine
11.678678199807727 : " $^FinishedLine
14.905855346233682 : # %^FinishedLine
15.98343143372184 : $ "^FinishedLine
16.053542916378102 : % #^FinishedLine
```

I need to sort my text file "Q.txt" which contains a double and a string.
It has been separated using " : " and at the end of each phrase there is ("^FinishedLine"). When I run this, all it is coming up with is a "NumberFormatException: empty string" error.

```
  public class Sorting {

      public static void sort() throws IOException {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Q.txt"));
        ArrayList<Qpair> set = new ArrayList<>();
        String line = "";
        while (s.hasNext()) {
          String[] parts = line.split(" : ");
          set.add(new Qpair(Double.parseDouble(parts[0]), parts[1]));
          s.useDelimiter("^FinishedLine");

        }


      s.close();

      System.out.println(set);

    }

    private static class Qpair{
      private double d;
      private String s;
      public Qpair(double d, String s){
        this.d = d;
        this.s = s;     
      }

      public double getDouble(){
        return d;
      }

      public String getString(){
        return s;
      }

    }

    private static class QpairCompare implements Comparator<Qpair>{
      public int compare(Qpair x, Qpair y){
        return (int) (x.getDouble() - y.getDouble());

      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read a txt file containing matrix form of data into 2d array of same dimensions as in the file using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828491/how-to-read-a-txt-file-containing-matrix-form-of-data-into-2d-array-of-same-dime)

Comment: @hutcec, be sure your 3rd line its not a new line for your code, or will fail

Comment: You can try to use Double.valueOf() instead of parseDouble(). It won't throw an exception (if it's really cause of your problems here)

Comment: I guess your problem its when you try to do split(":") of " ^FinishedLine" then the Double value of part[0] would be Double.valueof(" ^FinishedLine") and crash...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see: You are setting `line` to the empty string. You enter the `while` loop without changing `line`. You split this empty string at `:`. I admit I had to try it out to be sure: it yields an array of 1 element, an empty string. You try to parse this empty string from the array as a double.

And you tell us you get `NumberFormatException: empty string`. Sounds like agreement to me.

I hope you can figure out what code line is missing and where you should insert it?